# Process for publishing test-versions of product internally, and keeping a list of "what is in this version", when using Mercurial?

Tags: testing, mercurial, process, changelog

I need some concrete ideas for this.

We're looking at changing our version control system, and I'd like for us to use Mercurial. It would ease a lot of pain related to some internal processes, as well as pose some challenges.

One of those challenges is that the version control system we're currently using is not a distributed one, and thus has the concept of revision numbers for each changeset, which we've used internally.

Basically, when the programmer checks in the final change that fixes a case in our case management system, Visual Studio responds with which changeset number this became, and the programmer then affixes that to the case which basically says "If you're running a version of our product with the last version number this value, or higher, then you have all the changes in that version."

However, with Mercurial that doesn't work, as revision numbers can and will change as commits come in from different branches.

So I'm wondering how I can get something similar.

Note, this is not about release management. Releases are much more controlled, but on-going tests are more fluid, so we'd like to avoid having a tester continuously trying to figure out if the test-cases on his list are really available in the version he's testing on.

Basically, I need the ability for someone testing to see if the version they're testing on has the changes related to a test-case, or not.

I was considering the following:

1. The programmer commits, and grabs the hash of the changeset
2. The programmer affixes this to the case in our case tracker
3. The build process will have to tag (not in the Mercurial way) the version so that it knows which changeset it was built from
4. I have to make it easy to take the hash of the changeset our product was built from, look it up in the changeset log of the repository that is used for our build machine, and then figure out if the product changeset is the same as, or an ancestor of, each case in the test list.

So I have two questions:

1. Is this a feasible approach? I'm not adverse to creating a web application that makes this easy to handle
2. Does anyone know of an alternate process that would help me? I've looked at tagging, but it seems that tagging ends up adding merge pressure, is that something I want? (ie. adding/moving a tag ends up as a commit, which needs to be merged with the rest of the system)
3. Is there anything out there that would help me out of the box, that is, have someone made, or know of, something like this already?
4. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it right to say that you're looking for a lightweight tagging process linked to your build process?

I'm not keen on the idea of the programmer grabbing the last hash and sticking it somewhere else - sounds like the sort of manual process that you couldn't rely on happening. Would you be able to build a process around programmers adding the case number to their commit message so *something* could later link the commit to the original case? When the case was marked as "closed" you could pick up all commits against the case.

Lots of case control systems have this - [Fogbugz](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/4433/how-do-we-set-up-mercurial-source-control-integration), for example.

Comment: The problem is if I do a commit against a case now, then build kicks in, while it is running I commit a final time against the same case, and then signs the case as fixed and ready for test. I need to know how the tester can know that all my commits are part of the build or not. Linking the commits to the case doesn't really work unless I know that all the commits towards the case is part of the build.

Comment: I think you need a test system that controls what is and isn't pulled in. If you commit a case in your system, that shouldn't impact the builds on your test system. Once a case is flagged as complete, the changesets associated with that change can be pulled into the test system.

Answer (score 1):

Both bitbucket and google code keep a branching timeline, that shows visually what has been merged, by who, and when. I suspect that this might be what you want to do: it's a very simple way to resolve issue 4.

How they do that, I don't know, but the tools are out there. BitBucket offers commercial code hosting.